# MongoDB: Create a Separate Collection / Schema where each Item is an Array, not an Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql

I am new to databases & mongodb. I have the collections `Song` and `Line`. `Line` represents one line from the lyrics of a song. So far, I had the lines just embedded in `Song`:

**1: Embedded (and how I'd like it to look like)**

```
{
 title: 'This Charming Man',
 pages: 300,
 lines: [
  { content: 'I would go out tonight', ... },
  { content: 'but I haven't got a stitch to wear', ...}
 ]
}
```

Now I would like to move those lines into their own collection & just reference them. I know how to reference *objects*, so I implemented it this way for now:

```
const lyricsSchema = new Schema({
  lines: { type: [LineSchema], default: [] },
});
```

and in my `Song` schema:

```
lyrics: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Lyrics',
  },
```

**However:**
This *does* work, but I now when I query have an additional layer between my Song object & my line array, since now my `Lyrics` Object holds the `lines` array (which is totally expected):

**2: How it looks now, with a Song Schema & a Lyrics Schema**

```
{
 title: 'This Charming Man',
 pages: 300,
 lyrics: {
    lines: [
     { content: 'I would go out tonight', ... },
     { content: 'but I haven't got a stitch to wear', ...}
 }
 ]
}
```

How can I move the `lines` into a separate collection, but have the end result look like **1)**? (what I had initially, when it was still embedded). I want to turn my `lines` into a separate collection that does *not hold* an array, but *is* an array.

Comment: You could make each line be its own object, without the intermediate "Lyrics" object.

Comment: Or you can have a simple helper function in your code that hides the lookup for lines: `song.getLines() { return this.lyrics.lines }` or something like that.